# Closures with functions as object members

Tags: javascript, scope

My question sounds simple: does a function defined as an object member have closure over function's scope which contains the object?

For example:

```
    function foo() {
      /* some
       *  code*/

     var obj = {
            prop1: //something;
            prop2: //something;
            someCoolProp: function() {
                  //code
             }
     }
}
```

Does the `someCoolProp` function reference have closure over the scope of `foo`? Where is the anonymous function defined so if we gave it a name where would it be accessible?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your questions. What do you mean by "if we gave it a name"? Give it a name how?

Comment: I mean inside the expression instead of being created as an anonymous function it had some name `TestFunction` as an example

Comment: Then it would still be a function expression and its name wouldn't be visible outside.

Comment: So function names inside function expressions arent visible elsewhere?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Replace `/* some code */` and `//code` by actual code that demonstrates what you're asking about. Be explicit about modifications; don't say "*if we gave it a name*", show the code you're thinking of. Right now the essential parts of this question are only in your head, and you're giving us only vague instructions to recreate what you're thinking of in our own heads.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question sounds simple: does a function defined as an object member have closure over function's scope which contains the object?
>
> Does the `someCoolProp` function reference have closure over the scope of `foo`?

Yes. It being defined within the object initializer doesn't have any effect at all on what it closes over. It still closes over the context of the call to `foo` that created it.

> Where is the anonymous function defined so if we gave it a name where would it be accessible?

As of ES2015, that function *does* have a name: `someCoolProp`. (ES2015 added a lot of function name inference to the specification; a large number of "anonymous function expressions" no longer create anonymous functions, amusingly.) That name isn't added to any execution context's binding object (loosely, "scope"), though; the only reference to the function that exists is on the object's property of the same name.

But if you mean, if you used a named function expression:

```
var obj = {
    prop1: //something;
    prop2: //something;
    someCoolProp: function someNameHere() {
    //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------- added
        //code
    }
}
```

...the situation is the same: Because it's a function *expression*, the name isn't added to the context where it's defined. (Whereas with a function *declaration*, it is.)

Comment: Thank you! So functions inside function expressions are declared in some unreachable scope and are only visible after the point of the variable assigment through that variables name?

Comment: @BranTran - No, no hidden scope (unless it has default parameter values, another ES2015 thing, but that's a side point). It just doesn't get added directly to any scope at all. (If, again, by "scope" we mean where variables are stored, which isn't quite what "scope" means.) Nothing requires that all functions have a binding in an execution context that refers to them.

Answer (score 1):

> My question sounds simple: does a function defined as an object member have closure over function's scope which contains the object?

Yes, it has.

```js
function foo() {
    var bar = 42,
        obj = {
            prop1: 'something',
            prop2: 'something',
            someCoolProp: function() {
                console.log(bar);
            }
        };

    return obj;
}

foo().someCoolProp();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain the `foo().someCoolProp()` part: how do you call the `someCoolProp` function that is a property of the `obj` object as a member function of the `foo` function?

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't notice that the object is returned. Shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a `function` a new scope is created, that's means all property inside it are private so none other scope can call these property. Let me explain with different examples because it's really important to understand this.

---

Here, you can't call `x` in the `window` scope, `x` is only inside the `foo()` scope

```js
function foo() {
  var x = 'Hey';
  
  function transformX( val ){
    // I can call x because transformX is inside Foo()
    x = 'Ho';
  }
  
  return transformX(x);
}

console.log( foo() ); // 'Ho'
console.log( x ); // Reference Error can't read x
```

---

Here it's a ****** bad practice, I declare `y` without the `var` keyword, so at first `window` doesn't know `y` but during `bar()` execution `y` is declared & attached inside the `window` scope (default behavior) ! Always use a keyword declaration : `var` | `let` | 'const`

```js
function bar() {
  y = 'Hey';
  
  function transformX( val ){
    y = 'Ho';
  }
  return transformX(y);
}

console.log( y ); // 'Error y is not defined'
bar();
console.log( y ); // 'Ho'
```

---

This example is pretty hard than before, you can see a `people` variable inside the `peopleObject` and inside the `window` object. This practice is good to keep some variables like private.

```js
var peopleObject = function(){
  
  var people = {
    name: 'Yann',
    age: 25
  }
  
  function sayMyName(){
    console.log('Hi', people.name);
  }
  
  function getName(){
    return people.name;
  }
  
  return {
    name : getName,
    p: people
  };
  
};

var people = peopleObject();
console.log( people.name() );
console.log( people.p );
console.log( people.sayMyName() ); // error sayMyName is not a function
```

Hi hope it's gonna help you :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take notes.